# Avro schema record field name start from number

Tags: avro, avro-tools

Avro documentation says:

> The name portion of a fullname, record field names, and enum symbols must:
>
> - start with [A-Za-z_]
> - subsequently contain only [A-Za-z0-9_]

Is it possible somehow to escape the first rule and have record field name starting with digit, i.e. `123ColumnName`? Maybe via "escaping" or a special "notation"?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a field name starting with a digit by "escaping" it with an underscore (_).

```
{
    "namespace" : "com.test",
    "type" : "record",
    "name" : "digit",
    "fields": [ 
        { "name" : "_1ColumnName", "type" : ["null", "string"], "default" : null },
        { "name" : "_2ColumnName", "type" : ["null", "string"], "default" : null },
        { "name" : "_2ColumnName", "type" : ["null", "string"], "default" : null }
    ]
}
```

Although I wouldn't recommend this, since accessing the fields later on is a bit tricky. You may consider, for instance, naming your field as "f1ColumnName", "f2ColumnName" and so on, instead.